# How to set color goes beyond container from sides

Tags: html, css, styles, flexbox

On below example how can I set the `background-color` of the sidebar continue to the right side of the page?

PS: I have to use container to center the whole content.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/neginbasiri/pen/RGRwBG). Snippet below:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.columnContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.articleContainer {
  order: 1;
  width: 75%;
}
.articleSidebar {
  width: 25%;
  order: 2;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=columnContainer>
    <div class="articleContainer">article</div>
    <div class="articleSidebar">article sidebar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: apply `background-color` to `container`? Not sure what the issue here is...

Comment: @kukkuz the articleSidebar background-color should continues all the way to the right side of the page.

Comment: reset the default margin of `body` by `margin: 0` works for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. can you show it in the code?

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't work - if your screen is wider that 1366 still you have white space on right hand side.

Comment: That's because you have set `max-width` for `container` , you can remove that

Comment: I still wants my content (both columns) to be centered. but the background-color for the right column goes beyond the container from right hand side.

Comment: Check this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/ozLgJG?editors=0110)

Comment: So above 1366 you want the columns to be centered and the right colmn's background stretch to the far right end?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay the codepen you mentioned still has white space on right side. above 1366 I want the columns to be centered and the right colmn's background stretch to the far right end.